# FCM is automatically adding collapse_key to push notifications and I don't know why

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

We are using FCM in a server environment for our Push Notifications and we are getting some of our community complaining about some PNs not being delivered.

When we investigate the FCM logs in Big Query, we notice that there is a `collapse_key` being set for each message.

According to documentation, having a `collapse_key` discards all but the latest notification when an Android app comes back online.

However, we are not explicitly setting a `collapse_key` in our payloads - it seems that it is automatically being set.

We do not want our messages (chat messages) to be collapsed and it seems that there is no documentation on how to explicitly opt out of collapsing.

We've read all of the surrounding documentation and investigated the underlying sdks for hints on a collapse_key being set.

How do I explicitly opt out of `collapse_key` in FCM?

EDIT - adding code.

```
const messageOptions = {
  priority: 'high',
  contentAvailable: true,
  mutableContent: true
};

messaging.sendToDevice(
  device_token,
  {
    data,
    notification
  },
  messageOptions
).then(response => (do_some_stuff()));
```

Comment: Can you update your question to include the server code used in the FCM server request?

Comment: HI @JenPerson - I've added the code that we use for the admin sdk.

Comment: So far, it's unclear to me why a collapse key is being automatically set, but I'll look into it more. What are the values of the collapse keys you're seeing?

Comment: Also, have you witnessed firsthand messages collapsing? It's possible that BigQuery includes `collapse_key` because that analytics data is provided by FCM whether or not the value is set

Comment: We don't have programatic data on this (not sure how we would do this) but we have built a system that proves PNs are being received by our users which matches Firebase's delivery reports.

However, users are complaining that they aren't getting notifications. It may be the case that `collapse_key` is being added automatically. I'd be glad of this, as it would remove one more variable from our bug hunt!

Comment: I went ahead and tested this code myself, and the notifications do not collapse by default.

Comment: Have you checked if it's the same `collapse_key` value every time?

Comment: It is the same collapse_key if it's a `Display Notification`, if it's a `Data Notification` then it has the key `do_not_collapse`.